# Some shading troubles

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, color

I have some issues and I'd be so appreciative if u could help me. The problem is that the color is different on one part of a icon, I checked shading nodes etc. but nothing seems to be wrong there[image]

Comment: If that is a normal mesh object I'd be inclined to check the normals. Select the whole object in Edit mode and SHIFT-N to recalculate normals. If that doesn't cure it we'll need to see your blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Thank u so much! It did help

Comment: Good! You must have had those faces flipped.